# Could not select sibling using CSS Selector in Selenium

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, automated-tests

Selenium WebDriver throws InvalidSelectorException when trying to click on next sibling element using CSS Selector.

Consider my DOM looks like this:

```
<div class="checkbox-group">
   <div>     
       <span class="checkbox">::after</span> <!--click on this span makes the checkbox checked-->
       <span class="checkbox-name">Male</span> <!--click on this span doesn't make the checkbox checked-->
   </div>
   <div>
      <span class="checkbox">::after</span>
      <span class="checkbox-name">Female</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

And my Java code is:

```
@FindAll(@FindBy(css=".checkbox-name"))
List<WebElement> checkboxes;

public void selectCheckbox(String value){
    for(WebElement checkbox : checkboxes){
        String text = checkbox.getText();
        if(text.equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
            WebElement control = checkbox.findElement(By.cssSelector("+.checkbox"));//Exception thrown here     
            control.click();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception thrown as:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified. 
** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=+.checkbox}
```

Comment: My apologies, its typo mistake. I have updated the error stacktrace. My issue is still valid, can you please take a look at it now.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fetching the element by class `checkbox-name` and checking if it contains the `String value`, you can directly fetch that element using the `text` in the xpath.
After finding that element, you can use `following-sibling` in the xpath to get to the `span` which is clickable.

You can do all of this in one xpath only, like:

```
public void selectCheckbox(String value){
    WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='checkbox-group']//span[text()="+value+"]//following-sibling::span"));
    checkBox.click();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I m pretty aware of following-sibling xpath. But my tests are cucumber tests where name of checkboxes may not be exact as its found in application. I compare the texts irrespective of spaces, case insensitive, ignoring special characters and then click if name matched. Actually, my DOM contains ‘::after’ element before ‘name’ element which is stopping me using following-sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Before other people point out that this problem can be easily solved using xpath, let me tell you that I have that solution already. But intent of this question is to find out why selenium doesnt work even when my CSS selector is correct.

**Xpath solution:**

```
public void selectCheckbox(String value){
    for(WebElement checkbox : checkboxes){
        String text = checkbox.getText();
        if(text.equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
            WebElement control = checkbox.findElement(By.xpath("./parent::div/span[@class='checkbox']"));
            control.click();
        }
    }
}
```